# Add Databricks API to configure init script in existing bash script

Tags: databricks

**I would like to add the Databricks init script API in my exsiting bash script. How can I do this?** Here is the API provided by Databricks:

```
curl -n -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "cluster_id": "",
  "num_workers": 1,
  "spark_version": "8.4.x-scala2.12",
  "node_type_id": "$node_type",
  "cluster_log_conf": {
    "dbfs" : {
      "destination": "dbfs:/cluster-logs"
    }
  },
  "init_scripts": [ {
    "dbfs": {
      "destination": "dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/kafka_keytabs/CopyKrbFiles.sh"
    }
  } ]
}' https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/clusters/edit
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? do you want to upload init script in addition to cluster definition? Can you use databricks-cli?